# C TA-Lib functions in Python

Tags: python, c

I was wondering if any of you could give me guidance on whether it'd be possible to use some of these TA-LIB functions found [here](http://ta-lib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ta-lib/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/)  in a python script. I cant find the functions in any other language that I know...

I read [this](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html), so there seems to be some level of possibility, however I have little understanding of whats going on in the article since I dont know C at all. Oh and incase you are wondering TA-Lib is ported on python BUT its doesnt really build on mac and most people say they have issues with it.

So essentially, I can't get the whole app to work in swig, I was wondering if I could instead compile the function (not even sure if that makes sense) and use it in a python app (and hopefully some guidance on how to do so).

Comment: It is possible, but perhaps not simple. This post might help you: http://dpinte.wordpress.com/2010/04/22/interfacing-ta-lib-with-cython/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe there are three simple approaches you could take:

**SWIG**

TA-Lib comes with a Python wrapper that is generated by SWIG.  It hasn't been updated in a long time, so is hard-coded to build with Python 2.3.  Andy Hawkins wrote some [directions](http://blog.mediafederation.com/andy-hawkins/getting-ta-lib-to-work-with-python-2-6-swig-interface/) to get it to work with newer versions of Python.

**Cython**

I wrote a [TA-Lib python wrapper](http://mrjbq7.github.com/ta-lib/) that uses Cython to wrap all the functions in TA-Lib, and released it on Github.  It works really well for me, uses Numpy arrays, is 2-4 times faster, more "pythonic", and easier to install (works on Mac OS X) than the SWIG interface.

**Ctypes**

If you only need a small number of functions from the library, you can [use ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to make calls into the TA-Lib library.

Comment: Dude you are THE MAN. I went through and did like 15 of the functions in cython, was pulling my hair out when I realized I'd have to do them for a bunch more. Will definitely be using your Cython wrapper. Thanks SOOOOO MUCH.

Comment: Hello, I tried installing the through the instructions first. I had to install cython first and ran in to the problem of "gcc failed with exit status 1", i fixed that with deleting all the -myg (something)  from C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py. Worked fine and when i try to run "easy_install TA-Lib" it gives me the exact error "gcc failed with exit status 1". Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @user1234440 Did you ever get it working?  Feel free to make a bug report on my [Github](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib) project.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a single function in a library, yoyu be better of using ctypes - ctypes is a Python module in the standard library that allows to you to perform calls to libraries in native code.

You just have to check on the Python console how to obtain you TA-LIB as a Python object using ctypes, and how to call the function you need. Ctypes converts ints and strings automatically to C for you - you will need to perform some function anotation for other parameter types, though.